# Fetching Data From Two Or More Api Synchronously

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm using angularjs in my project:

```
var getApi = function(){
     $http.get(link)
    .then(function(response) {$scope.data = response.data.api});   
}
```

But this time, I have to fetch link from two or more links. How can I do this? 
I have to fetch data from 5 api Synchronously and get sum of data.

Comment: do you mean asynchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var getApi = function(){
    $q.all([
         $http.get(link),
         $http.get(link),
         $http.get(link),
         $http.get(link),
         $http.get(link)
    ]).then(function(resultArray) {
        // resultArray will now contain 5 objects with responses  
    });
}
```

More info about `$q.all` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Comment: when I iterate over resultArray, I have 0 and 1

Comment: Could you give me a plunkr ?

Comment: it's ok. Thanks for help :)